# Updating textarea using ng-model with JSON object on different popover

Tags: angularjs, json

I am having different pop Over on same page by clicking on on-click popover getting opened with text area. By using `ng-model`, I am trying to fetch Item.description in with different popover with different text area.

```
<div id="popover">
<textarea ng-model="$ctrl.test.item.description" cols="4" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

Current Result:-Producing same result to all popover textarea.

Expected Result:-From Json object It should fetch different description in different popover as per I saved.

Should be used only angular.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ng-model with ng-bind

```
<div id="popover">
<textarea ng-bind="$ctrl.test.item.description" cols="4" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

i guess this might help

Comment: i am having different popover on different click but same text box.I have solved it by using the following logic .I am maintaining index on click of icon and passing to opening method

Comment: cont.config.populate.note= cont.config.populate[index].note

Comment: thanks for your suggestion .by using ng-model only it works for me .

Answer (score 0):

this is the code inside popover.

call it at the time of clicking of icon
  cont.item.descripiton= cont.config.item[index].description